# How to cut vertices and faces connected to points lower than some value in pyvista?

Tags: python, vtk, grass, pyvista

So when one exports `r.out.vtk` from Grass GIS we get a bad surface with -99999 points instead of nulls:

[image]

I want to remove them, yet a simple clip is not enough:

```
pd = pv.read('./pid1.vtk')
pd = pd.clip((0,1,1), invert=False).extract_surface()
p.add_mesh(pd ) #add atoms to scene
p.show()
```

resulting in:
[image]

So I wonder how to keep from it only top (> -999) points and connected vertices - in order to get only the top plane (it is curved\not flat actually) using pyvista?

link to [example .vtk](https://pastebin.com/4EDAQziH)

Comment: Does `pd.threshold` not work for your use case? See https://docs.pyvista.org/core/filters.html?highlight=threshold#pyvista.DataSetFilters.threshold

Comment: nope -  results are same as for clipping approach

Comment: Any chance you can provide example data to play with? I don't think I'll be able to help without that.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: added pastebin link to  .vtk file contents - tey are in form of ASCII text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this and there isn't...

You could use pyvista's [`threshold`](https://docs.pyvista.org/core/filters.html#pyvista.DataSetFilters.threshold) filter with `all_scalars=True` as long as you have only one set of scalars:

```py
import pyvista as pv

pd = pv.read('./pid1.vtk')
pd = pd.threshold(-999, all_scalars=True)

plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(pd) #add atoms to scene

plotter.show()
```

Since `all_scalars` starts filtering based on every scalar array, this will only do what you'd expect if there are no other scalars. Furthermore, unfortunately there seems to be [a bug in pyvista](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/pull/1488) (expected to be fixed in version 0.32.0) which makes the use of this keyword impossible.

What you can do in the meantime (if you don't want to use pyvista's main branch before the fix is released) is to threshold the data yourself using numpy:

```py
import pyvista as pv

pd = pv.read('./pid1.vtk')

scalars = pd.active_scalars
keep_inds = (scalars > -999).nonzero()[0]
pd = pd.extract_points(keep_inds, adjacent_cells=False)

plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(pd) #add atoms to scene

plotter.show()
```

The main point of both `all_scalars` (in `threshold`) and `adjacent_cells` (in `extract_points`) is to only keep cells where every point satisfies the condition.

With both of the above I get the following figure using your data:
[image: fixed mesh: small flat surface without spurious jumps]

Comment: Thank you!))) It saves a lot of time and enables the use of solely pyvista 
 for my case. `pd.active_scalars_info.name` instead of `pd.active_scalars_info.name` for generalisation=)

Comment: @DuckQueen good idea, thanks, I've edited my answer to make it more flexible.

Comment: @DuckQueen also, I've just realized that the `all_scalars` keyword does two things, and you only need one. So you'd only be able to use it (even after the bugfix) if there are no other scalars on the array.